# Images not found in the same path

Tags: latex

When I compile my .tex file, the following error is shown:

> ```
> LaTeX Warning: File `imagem2.png' not found on input line 767. !
> Package pdftex.def Error: File `imagem2.png' not found.
> ```

All files in the same paste of .tex file are not found.

I've tried these commands, but don't work:

```
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.JPG}
\graphicspath{...}
```

And I have these commands in my .tex file:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: What does your `\includegraphics` line look like? Where are your PNG files in relation to your .tex file? Why are you declaring `JPG` as a graphics extension when you are using `PNG` files?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: You missed the tag pop-up you got when adding the [latex] tag right?

Comment: Sorry guys, I change the OS and Linux is sensitive case, but in Windows it's not happen.